# MySQL Booleans and stored procedures

Tags: mysql, node.js, boolean, mysql2

I am trying to save some booleans in a MySQL table via stored procedures from NodeJS, executing it with mysql2.

Important: I did `SET @@global.sql_mode= '';` to disable strict mode.

Lets say I have this table

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`booleanField` BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And I want to add a new row with a `{ someBoolean: true }`:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(
    IN DATA JSON
)

BEGIN

  SET @someBoolean      = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.someBoolean'));

  INSERT INTO test_table (
    booleanField
  ) VALUES (
    @someBoolean
  );

  SELECT 
    @someBoolean AS receivedValue,
    id,
    booleanField
  FROM test_table;


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And I execute it:

```sql
CALL test_procedure('{"someBoolean": true}');
```

The result of this is a new row with some interesting result:

Running all this code in the MySQL terminal client I receive this:

```
+---------------+----+--------------+
| receivedValue | id | booleanField |
+---------------+----+--------------+
| true          |  1 |            0 |
+---------------+----+--------------+
```

So even then the received value was `true`,the boolean field was set as `0`.

I can make it work checking if `@someBoolean` is a string `"true"`, and setting it to TRUE, etc.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(
    IN DATA JSON
)

BEGIN
  DECLARE CASTED_VOTE INT; -- NEW
  SET @someBoolean      = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.someBoolean'));

  -- NEW
  IF      @someBoolean = "true"  THEN SET  CASTED_VOTE = 1;
  ELSEIF  @someBoolean = "false" THEN SET  CASTED_VOTE = 0;
  ELSE SET                          CASTED_VOTE = NULL;
  END IF;
  -- END NEW

  INSERT INTO test_table (
    booleanField
  ) VALUES (
    CASTED_VOTE
  );

  SELECT 
    CASTED_VOTE, -- NEW
    @someBoolean AS receivedValue,
    id,
    booleanField
  FROM test_table;


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Execute again…

```sql
CALL test_procedure('{"someBoolean": true}');
```

And voila:

```
+-------------+---------------+----+--------------+
| CASTED_VOTE | receivedValue | id | booleanField |
+-------------+---------------+----+--------------+
|           1 | true          |  1 |            1 |
+-------------+---------------+----+--------------+
```

But that means that I have to do the same thing over and over in all my queries.
What I'm doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: `SET @someBoolean = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.someBoolean'));` returns not numeric `TRUE = 1` but string `'true'`.

Comment: Yes, I said that in the question

Comment: So use `INSERT INTO test_table (booleanField) VALUES (@someBoolean = 'true');`

Comment: Can't understand this: may you provide a working example given the stored procedure I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(
    IN DATA JSON
)

BEGIN

  SET @someBoolean      = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.someBoolean'));

  INSERT INTO test_table (
    booleanField
  ) VALUES (
    @someBoolean = 'true'
  );

  SELECT 
    @someBoolean AS receivedValue,
    id,
    booleanField
  FROM test_table;


END
```

or

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(
    IN DATA JSON
)

BEGIN

  SET @someBoolean := JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.someBoolean')) = 'true';

  INSERT INTO test_table (
    booleanField
  ) VALUES (
    @someBoolean
  );

  SELECT 
    @someBoolean AS receivedValue,
    id,
    booleanField
  FROM test_table;


END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffda146e5b3ba514fd5e0569cdb253b7)

---

> what if I want to pass null? CALL test_procedure('{"someBoolean": "null"}'); – Emille C.

```
SET @someBoolean := CASE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.someBoolean'))
                    WHEN 'true' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'false' THEN 0
                    END;
```

Any value except `'true'` or `'false'` (including the parameter absence) will be treated (and assigned of course) as `NULL`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d39182696accc8bfd91e2b65f25c5c37)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really interesting; what if I want to pass null? `CALL test_procedure('{"someBoolean": "null"}');`

Comment: @EmilleC. Updated. PS. `"null"` is string, not NULL.